# Strange RU/s usage when using Azure Cosmos DB (mongo interface from java)

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

We are using Azure cosmos DB and we are accessing it from Java using the mongo API

Some simple queries that usually use about 4 RUs sometime take about 1500 RU's and we get the message "rate is too large"

If we do the same query from the azure portal UI we always get the lower RU's consumption

Example Document:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5c40a6e3f6fe4d1fec5f092e"
    },
    "attempts": 0,
    "status": {

        "confirmed": false,
        "nSent": true
    }
    ...
    rest of non relevant fields
}
```

if i translate the query to SQL is will look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.status.confirmed = true and (c.status.nSent=null or c.status.nSent=false) and (c.attempts=null or c.attempts<10)
```

2 important notes:

1. we do not use the shard key in this query. I don't know if it is relevant here or not
2. note that we check that c.status.nSent does not exists (=null) or that it is equal to false. If we remove the part that check that c.status.nSent is null then the query goes fine. This is the strange part...

Example of the query as azure sees it in the their log:

```
(((r1["p1"]["p2"] = true) AND (((r1["p1"]["p3"] ?? null) = null) OR (r1["p1"]["p3"] = false))) AND ((((r1["p4"] ?? null) = null) OR (r1["p4"] <= 10)) AND (r1["p5"] >= 67)))","parameters":[]}"}}
```

I have also tried to replace this part of the query

```
(c.status.nSent=null or c.status.nSent=false)
```

with

```
(c.status.nSent!=true)
```

hoping that it will also apply for document that do not have this property but the results are the same

Our average RU/s usage is 40 RU/s and our limit is 4000 RU/s so there should be a lot of spare RU/s for this query

On the exception we get we see this:

```
RequestCharge: 0.38
```

Comment: Do you have an Azure support plan? If not, can you please send your Azure subscription GUID to AzCommunity at Microsoft dot com and instructions will be sent back to have this investigated. If you do have an Azure support plan a support ticket should be opened to investigate this further. It appears the REST interface via the Portal is providing consistent result but from the Java SDK, you are seeing inconsistent results. Furthermore, there is a planned release for the Mongo API with regard to the Aggregation Framework, so improvements are being made.

Comment: I am escalating this to the product group and it would be helpful to at least know your Java SDK version, and any other relevant details. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, We have support plan and i will open a ticket. Will also provide more information tommorow

Comment: We are using this version: compile 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:3.9.1'

Comment: Can you provide more details about how you are using the API? Is this embedded in an application? How is the data and query is being passed to the API? Need more details. You can follow up via email instead of posting details here. Thanks! Product Group wants to know more...